# How should I send contacts via email?

Tags: email, contacts

I often experience problems sending and getting contact information in mobile devices due to some weird incompatibilities (they often arrive garbled, empty or don't arrive at all). So I use plain SMS text, which is uncomfortable on both sides. Therefore I have doubts on attaching vCards to emails.

Is it likely that the attached vCard will not be opened correctly?

Is it safer inserting contact data to the email body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it all depends on your interlocutors:

- If they are a minimum tech-savvy I would just send the vcard as they should know they can open it with any text editor if they need to.
- If they are not tech-savvy, I would insert the contact data to the email body and maybe add the vcard saying the contact information are attached as well.
- In case you're not sure, it's a good idea to attach both vcard and plain text.